# After successful login the get and post api dosent work

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

I have feature modules - **Login** and **User** which are lazy-loaded.
And the single service - `app.service` provided in the `app.module`

The lazyloading flow:

- App.Module  -> imports LayoutModule (Which has all the layout components like header,footer,sidebar along with  in its template)
- LayoutModule -> Routes to Login and User Modules through lazyloading set up.

When  I call the login API `POST /api/login` from `app.service` through the `login` feature module, the API works and I get the success response.

Now when i call the API `GET /api/userInfo` from `app.service` in the same login feature module after the login API is called (in the data part of the subscribe function), I get the response with `302` and redirects me to `404` stating not logged-in.

But when I create the demo project an simply call the API's in the same `app.component` through the single `app.service` in get the response for all the API's.

As U am new to to Angular, I may be doing something wrong with services while lazy-loading.

Please provide me the solution or any references for implementing the service while lazy-loading the `feature` module.

Even all the API's work perfect when tested through the postman.

I'm following these procedures to call APIs:

1. `login.component.ts` (from Login feature module)

   ```js
   onSubmit() {
     this.submitted = true;
     //this.loading = true;
     const type = 'Customer';
     console.log(this.submitted);
     console.log(this.loginForm.value);

     const formData = new FormData();
     formData.append('username', this.f.username.value);
     formData.append('password', this.f.password.value);
     formData.append('type', type);

     // stop here if form is invalid
     if (this.loginForm.invalid) {
       return;
     }
     /* if (this.f.rememberMe) {
         localStorage.setItem()
     } */


     this.authenticationService.login(formData)
       .subscribe(
         data => {
           console.log(data);
           this.getUserInfo();
           this.router.navigate(['/']);
         },
         error => {
           this.error = error;
           this.loading = false;
         }
       );
   }


   getUserInfo() {
     this.userInfo
       = this.appService.getUserInfoById().subscribe(
         (data) => {
           this.userInfo = data;
           console.log(this.userInfo);
         },
         (error) => {
           console.log(error);
         }
       );
   }

   login(formData: FormData): Observable < any >
     {
       const httpOptions = {
         headers: new HttpHeaders({
           'Content-Type': 'application/json'
         })
       };
       return this.http.post<any>('/api/login',
         formData, {
           withCredentials: true
         }).pipe(map(user => {
           if (user) {
             console.log(user);
             localStorage.setItem('currentUser',
               JSON.stringify(user));
           }
           return user;
         }));
     }

   getUserInfoById(): Observable < any > {
     return this.http.get<any>
       ('/api/user/getUserInfo').pipe(
         catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
           if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
             console.log('Error from network');
             console.error('An error occurred:',
               error.error.message);
           } else {
             console.log('Error from backend');
             console.log(error.error);
           }
           return observableThrowError(error.error);
         }));
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if it is not obvious on first sight, but with this code you have one subscription within another one.

```
this.authenticationService.login(formData).subscribe(
              data => {
                 console.log(data);
                 this.getUserInfo();
                 this.router.navigate(['/']);  
               },
              error => {
                 this.error = error;
                 this.loading = false;
               }
             );
          }


          getUserInfo() {
             this.userInfo 
                     =this.appService.getUserInfoById().subscribe(
             (data) => {
                     this.userInfo = data;
                      console.log(this.userInfo);
                },
             (error) => {
                     console.log(error);
                }
                );
               }
```

Don't do that, never! Please map the observable instead.

```
loginData$: Observable<LoginData> = this.authenticationService.login(formData);
userInfo$: Observable<UserInfo> = loginData$.pipe(
  switchMap(loginData => this.appService.getUserInfoById(loginData.userId))
);

userInfo$.pipe(/*don't forget to unsubscribe*/).subscribe(userInfo => this.userInfo = userInfo)
```

Even better: Don't subscribe at all and use async pipe instead

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the above solution.

Comment: As i'm very new to angular, can you please give some reference links for the above solutions so that I can learn how to do async call for the api's.

Comment: I am using angular 8.

Comment: https://malcoded.com/posts/angular-async-pipe/ :: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html

Comment: When you call http please always try to avoid subscriptions. async pipe and rxjs operators are very strong together. I know it takes some time to understand them, but it is worth it.